# Google Chrome is using wrong microphone

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, monterey

In settings > Privacy and Security > Site settings > Microphone, I set the microphone to be the aggregate device I made.

But chrome still uses the default microphone. I have restarted chrome several times, repeatedly check that "aggregate device" is still the selected microphone even after restarting, but all microphone testing sites, and all video calling sites, still just hear the default built-in microphone, not the aggregate device.

How can I either:

- make Chrome actually use the aggregate device as its microphone
- route system audio through the built-in microphone so chrome will hear it all anyway (or trick chrome into thinking the aggregate device is my built-in microphone)

Comment: Can you test this out in Firefox and/or Safari?  Can you select and use the aggregate device in those browsers?

Comment: @allan not in either of them because they use the system preferences setting not a browser setting (they do work if I change the system setting though, I have also tested in quicktime player and logic that the aggregate device works)

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand the first part of your comment.  Did you test them or not?

Comment: @allan it works in firefox, but has to be changed in system preferences. In Safari, no microphone works for me right now. In Chrome, even after changing system preferences, and restarting chrome, it still doesn't work frustratingly